Do I need IDistributedCache when using Open ID Connect for single sign-on?
I've seen a variety of examples of authenticating users, and sometimes some form of persistent cache is used, particularly when doing things like calling downstream APIs. My use case is authentication only - once I know who a user is, their roles/rights are going to be coming from another internal mechanism.
We release several times a day, using a blue/green pattern, and I'm concerned that without a persistent cache users will be randomly kicked out. However, locally, authentication state seems to entirely decided by the presence of a cookie.
Can anyone with expertise in OpenID Connect tell me whether, or in what circumstances, a persistent cache is required? I'm especially interested in how to configure that in the middleware - AddOpenIDConnect() doesn't seem to have anything cache related; however, the Microsoft.Identity.* packages to seem to explicitly support caches of different types.
I have tried to determine when a persistent cache is required by searching various development sites, looking at OIDC samples, and reviewing some of the code used to build the various middleware extensions.

You can speed up the actual login process by caching data needed, like clients, scopes etc. However, for the actual login session, all data is stored in the cookie. As long as you use the same dataprotection in all instances of your service, a redeploy will not affect the login session for the user.

Thank you @Marcus. If you make your comment into an answer, I can accept...

Is a persistent cache required in OpenID Connect?
No.
However, with a cache, you can speed up the login process by caching frequently fetched data.
That could be for example client configurations (secrets, redirect URIs etc) or frequently requested claims (roles, permissions etc).
Will users be randomly kicked out without a persistent cache?
No.
After a successful signin by the user, the identity server will set a cookie to persist the session for the user.
The cookie data is encrypted by the data protection api (read more here).
As long as each instances of the service is using the same data protection, user sessions will be unaffected by redeploys or scaling of the service.

If we are talking about the ASP.NET Core client, the authentication cookie by default contains your user and optionally your tokens. So, out of the box, therer is no need for a cache.
However, to ensure the cookie can be decrypted across deployments, you need to persist the data protection keyring in some place, as I described in this blog post
Persisting the ASP.NET Core Data Protection Key Ring in Azure Key Vault. It talks about why you should configure it and store it somewhere.
If you have multiple instances of your ASP.NET Client, then the Data Protection should use the same keyring.
Then, storing everything in the cookie can result in large cookies, and to reduce the size, then you might want to introduce a cache, as I described in this blog post: Improving ASP.NET Core Security By Putting Your Cookies On A Diet
as described in that blog post, adding a cache can also improve your security during signout.

Thank you for these links, very helpful!
